# quicksort bug not found

Tags: c++, debugging, sorting, quicksort

after working a whole day on this, i cannot find what is wrong with my code, i cannot find where my error is. can someone please help me figure out what i did wrong?

```
void a_quick(int array[], int i, int j){
    //Array Quick Sort
    if ((j - i) < 2){
        return;
    }
    int top = j;
    int bot = i;
    int p_location = i + (j + i) / 2;
    int pivot = array[p_location];
    while (i < j){
        while (array[i] < pivot){
            i++;
        }
        while (array[j] > pivot){
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j){
            swap(array[i], array[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    a_quick(array, bot, p_location);
    a_quick(array, p_location + 1, top);

}
```

running the code on 64k int arrays will crash the computer, and i need to get it to run on 128k.

im getting:

```
Test Array:
703 322 673 141 253 547 662 37 723 529 316 190 288 40 264 446 890 370 6 393

Quick Sort w Array:
6 37 40 141 253 190 316 288 264 322 393 370 446 529 723 662 890 547 673 703
```

Comment: @Muggen the array is **effectively** passed by reference due to pointer decay.

Comment: Either use qsort() or use the [homework] tag.

Comment: @Karl ye sorry. Did not read correct.

Comment: @Hans Passant: actually it should be `std::sort()` :)

Comment: what?? what is going on?

Comment: what is the output that you expect, and what is actually happening?

Comment: We need more data. Like the data set you are using that does not work.

Comment: OK, looks like you're not sorting the complete array ... perhaps you could print the the range of the array on each call.

Comment: You might also ask yourself what happens when there are more values smaller than the pivot than larger.

Comment: the range of the array? im using `rand()` and modding by 1000

Comment: Sorry, bad terminology (or maybe a bad edit). Just before you assign `top`, write a loop that prints every element in the range `i` to `j`. Just like you did for the entire array. Do this for every call (with each call on a separate line).

Comment: i would, but that would take forever to print (64k, 128k integers)

Comment: In your sample above, you showed 20 values. That's the most that you should print. And since Quicksort is logN, you should print a total of 9 lines of output. But it looks like you got your answer without having to do any debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works fine for me

```
   void a_quick(int array[], int i, int j){
    //Array Quick Sort

    int top = j;
    int bot = i;
    int p_location = (j + i) / 2;
    int pivot = array[p_location];
    do {
        while (array[i] < pivot)i++;
        while (array[j] > pivot)j--;
        if (i <= j){
            swap(array[i], array[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while (i<=j);
    if (bot<j) a_quick(array, bot, j);// problem is most likely here
    if (i<top) a_quick(array, i, top);// or here
}
```

Comment: can you explain why the last 2 ifs are needed? now its sorting right, so thanks!, but its still crashing

Comment: why not? it seems to have fixed the problem

Comment: @Martin York: Can you think of a test case which would reveal a possible flaw? Can't really see anything wrong with the code

Comment: @Martin York: you really got me thinking with it.
I know that the best possible way of choosing pivot values is to get random indexes between i and j, not sticking to first, last or middle element as in this case, to avoid O(n2) complexity for almost sorted sequences, but.. but here pivot is the middle value, as far as I can see, and it's always in the range between i and j, so I gather it must be a legitimate implementation of quicksort. 
Somebody please correct me.

Comment: @matcheek: Take that back. for some reason I was reading that as `(j - i) / 2` (the original posted code), But you have `(j + i) / 2` which does work.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the last two lines should read:

```
a_quick(array, bot, p_location - 1);
a_quick(array, p_location + 1, top);
```

Another problem is that you need to be prepared to move the pivot around (and keep track of its index). Your code would only work if the pivot already happens to be in the correct spot, which is unlikely.

For comparison, take a look at the several versions of the pseudocode available in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Comment: im trying to mix the pivot back in and move it along in the next recursion or something like that

Comment: i have. i gave up on those yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather broken. You need to move the pivot item out of the way (conventionally to the beginning of the array you are partitioning) since it's very unlikely that half the elements are less than the pivot and half greater.

And as others have said, you're including the pivot in both sub partitions when you recurse.

I would start by proving one partition run works (i.e don't recurse for now, stop when the partitioning is done, and check the array is now how you would expect)

Comment: OK. so now's the time to dig deeper. What's your test array? Did you change the code to move the partition? (consider an array { 9,9,9,5,9,9,1} - you can't partition it on 5 and leave the 5 where it is)

Answer (score 1):

The way you compute the pivot has a problem. Ask yourself what happens when the indices are 5 and 9. Instead of this:

```
p_location = (j - i) / 2;
```

Try something more like:

```
p_location = i + (j - i) / 2;
```

Comment: ok... i think its stopped crashing from going to weird indexes. thanks

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
void a_quick(int array[], int i, int j){
//Array Quick Sort
if (j <= i) return; // change here (j - i) < 1 (not 2)

int top = j;
int bot = i;
int p_location = (j + i) / 2; // change here - by + so you pick the middle
int pivot = array[p_location];
while (i < j){
    while (array[i] < pivot){
        i++;
    }
    while (array[j] > pivot){
        j--;
    }
    if (i <= j){
        swap(array[i], array[j]);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
a_quick(array, bot, j); // change here (dont use p_loc, use i and j)
a_quick(array, i, top); // and here
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
void a_quick(int array[], int i, int j){
    //Array Quick Sort
    if ((j - i) < 2){
        return;
    }
    int top = j;
    int bot = i;
    int p_location = (j - i) / 2;
    int pivot = array[p_location];
    while (i < j){
        while (array[i] < pivot){
            i++;
        }
        while (array[j] > pivot){
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j){
            std::swap(array[i], array[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    a_quick(array, bot, p_location);// problem is most likely here
    a_quick(array, p_location, top - 1);// or here
}

int main()
{
    // int d[] = { 5, 1, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3, 7, 9, 0};
    int d[] = { 5, 1, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3, 7, 0, 9};
    a_quick(d, 0, 9);

    std::copy(d, d+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
}

> g++ sort.cpp
> ./a.exe
0124356789 >
```

And it worked fine.
What we really need is an example of it failing.

Hopefully with a full test harness that just compiles and runs and shows the error.

Comment: im running this on 128k int arrays, and its crashing

Comment: Test Array:
703 322 673 141 253 547 662 37 723 529 316 190 288 40 264 446 890 370 6 393
Quick Sort:
6 37 40 141 253 190 316 288 264 322 393 370 446 529 723 662 890 547 673 703

Comment: It looks sort of sorted. But thats not the point. How am I supposed to know that is the expected output.

Comment: It's a sort routine. The expected output is the array elements in order. Not sort of sorted

Comment: @Paul: You missed the point. Humans are horrible at checking this kind of thing. You need some automated method to validate that the output matches some expected output. The original question had no input values and no output values. I got a set of unique values back looked correct to me.

Comment: If you say so. My opinion differs

Comment: @Paul: OK So what do you think would happen if I changed the input to: int d[] = { 5, 1, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3, 7, 0, 9}; Then for this input it is sorted and the algorithm is correct? The point being that without a valid set of inputs and outputs it would is imposable to verify the claim. Which is why when filing a bug report on a code you not only need the exact steps to reproduce the bug but also the exact input (and expected output). In this simple case we could make up data that may or may not work, but that does not mean we would fix the bug as we may be hitting a different error than the OP.

Comment: @Paul: You also not that the first response from 'calccrypto' is: `im running this on 128k int arrays, and its crashing`. Well the code did not crash for me, so in terms of working it worked (in it did not crash).

Comment: I've not changed my opinion. Say what you like, I'm ducking out at this point

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void a_quick(int array[], int i, int j){
    //Array Quick Sort
    if ((j - i) < 2){
        return;
    }
    int top = j;
    int bot = i;

    // Bug 1: Pick something in the correct range.
    int pivot = array[i + (j-i)/2];
    while (i < j){
        while (array[i] < pivot){
            i++;
        }
        while (array[j] > pivot){
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j)
        {
            // Bug 2: swap is in the std namespace
            std::swap(array[i], array[j]);

            // Bug 3: Don't increment the pointers.
            //        What if you hit the pivot point.
        }
    }
    // The split is not at where you selected the pivot point.
    // As that could be any number and it may not split evenly.
    // So you pick either of i or j. I picked j as the mid point
    // One sort upto j the other sorts from j+1 to the end.
    a_quick(array, bot, j );
    a_quick(array, j+1 , top );
}


int main()
{
    int d[] = { 703, 322, 673, 141, 253, 547, 662, 37, 723, 529, 316, 190, 288, 40, 264, 446, 890, 370, 6, 393 };
    int size = sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]);

    a_quick(d, 0, size - 1 );

    std::copy(d, d+size, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```